# Using SQLModel to have multiple tables with same columns

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic, sqlmodel

Let's say I have two SQL tables `address` and `email` tables.

For the `address` table I may have the following generic fields:

1. `postal_code`
2. `street_name`

and additionally, I would want the following two fields:

3. `is_verified`, of type `Enum` with only one of the three variants in `Unverified`, `Verified`, `InProgress`
4. `in_progress_description`, a `String` of a comment on the progress status

Similarly, for the `email` table, I would want the following generic field:

1. `email_addr` of type `pydantic.EmailStr`

and also the fields `is_verified` and `in_progress_description`.

Should I create a mixin like the following for the verifiability of the two tables (SQLModels) or how should I write my `Email` and `Address` classes to avoid duplicating codes for `is_verified` and `in_progress_description` fields?

=== Mixin ===

```
class VerifiableMixin:
    verification_status: VerificationStatusEnum = VerificationStatusEnum.Unverified
    verification_description: str = None
```

Then have the `Email(SQLModel, table=True)` subclassing it too.

```
class Email(SQLModel, VerifiableMixin, table=True):
    email_addr: EmailStr
```

=== SQLModel ===

```
class VerifiableBaseSQLModel:
    verification_status: VerificationStatusEnum = Field(default=VerificationStatusEnum.Unverified)
    verification_description: str = Field(default=None)
```

```
class Email(SQLModel, VerifiableBaseSQLModel, table=True):
    email_addr: EmailStr
```

Answer (score 1):

In terms of structure and normalization, I would have a new table called status and add to both tables the foreign key.
So we will get something like this:

Address

| id | postal_code | street_name | status_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10001 | whichever avenue | 1 |

Status

| id | current | description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Unverified | situation's description |

then you could have an audit table to save a history of changes if one day you will need to get some statistics for example to know the time in which each status is holding or something like this.
The same ought to apply to the email table.